# Fetch device location from local web page

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, google-chrome

How do i fetch the **latitude and longitude** of the android device from a **local html page** in chrome using **javascript** and **jquery** ?

**Chrome** doesn't fetch location nor does it ask for user permission(**i think its because of its security**).

**Mozilla** on the other hand does this better, but my html pages are compatible with chrome for many other reasons(**not much security**).

I have tried the **HTML5 geoLocation api** too, but doesn't help in chrome.

Comment: What happens when you call `getCurrentPosition`? You could pass a second callback to see if there was an error (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation.getCurrentPosition). One possible reason: Are you accessing your page from the local file system? Chrome doesn't allow to use the Geolocation API in this case.

Comment: Yes, i am accessing my page from the local system. Chrome does allow to access location from the local system, but every time i have to open chrome from cmd,setting its allow files access flag.

Comment: Is there anyway where i can set this allow access flag to true always for chrome

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.blogspot.de However, it would be better to run a local web server instead.